# How to force parquet dtypes when saving pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, dask, pyarrow

Is there a way to force a parquet file to encode a `pd.DataFrame` column as a given type, even though all values for the column are null? The fact that parquet automatically assigns "null" in its schema is preventing me from loading many files into a single `dask.dataframe`.

Trying to cast the pandas column using `df.column_name = df.column_name.astype(sometype)` didn't work.

**Why I'm asking this**

I want to load many parquet files into a single `dask.dataframe`. All files were generated from as many instances of `pd.DataFrame`, using `df.to_parquet(filename)`. All dataframes have the same columns, but for some a given column might contain only null values. When trying to load all files into the `dask.dataframe` (using `df = dd.read_parquet('*.parquet')` , I get the following error:

```
Schema in filename.parquet was different.
id: int64
text: string
[...]
some_column: double

vs

id: int64
text: string
[...]
some_column: null
```

**Steps to reproduce my problem**

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
a = pd.DataFrame(['1', '1'], columns=('value',))
b = pd.DataFrame([None, None], columns=('value',))
a.to_parquet('a.parquet')
b.to_parquet('b.parquet')
df = dd.read_parquet('*.parquet')  # Reads a and b
```

This gives me the following:

```
ValueError: Schema in path/to/b.parquet was different. 
value: null
__index_level_0__: int64
metadata
--------
{b'pandas': b'{"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"na'
            b'me": null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_'
            b'type": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns":'
            b' [{"name": "value", "field_name": "value", "pandas_type": "empty'
            b'", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": null, "fi'
            b'eld_name": "__index_level_0__", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_t'
            b'ype": "int64", "metadata": null}], "pandas_version": "0.22.0"}'}

vs

value: string
__index_level_0__: int64
metadata
--------
{b'pandas': b'{"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"na'
            b'me": null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_'
            b'type": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns":'
            b' [{"name": "value", "field_name": "value", "pandas_type": "unico'
            b'de", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": null, "'
            b'field_name": "__index_level_0__", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy'
            b'_type": "int64", "metadata": null}], "pandas_version": "0.22.0"}'}
```

Notice how in one case we have `"pandas_type": "unicode"` and in the other we have `"pandas_type": "empty"`.

**Related questions that didn't provide me with a solution**

- [How to specify logical types when writing Parquet files from PyArrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172428/how-to-specify-logical-types-when-writing-parquet-files-from-pyarrow)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you instead use `fastparquet`, you can achieve chat you want

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
a = pd.DataFrame(['1', '1'], columns=('value',))
b = pd.DataFrame([None, None], columns=('value',))
a.to_parquet('a.parquet', object_encoding='int', engine='fastparquet')
b.to_parquet('b.parquet', object_encoding='int', engine='fastparquet')

dd.read_parquet('*.parquet').compute()
```

gives

```
   value
0    1.0
1    1.0
0    NaN
1    NaN
```

Comment: Interestingly, the dtype of the column is float64

Comment: NaN is implemented as float 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na

Comment: Is there any solution  using `pyarrow` ? We had a similar problem and ran `repartition`  (heavy process but worked)

Comment: parquet reading and writing were recently refactored, worth trying again

Comment: @mdurant can you please clarify why using fastparquet works? I'm facing a similar issue with Dask DataFrames and can't figure out why I can store them to disk with fastparquet but not with pyarrow.
In fact, dask's `to_parquet` method even ignores the argument `schema` when the engine being used is `fastparquet` and I really can't figure out why.

Comment: Basically, fastparquet gives you this lever to be explicit, where arrow decides for you. Only the arrow backend supports (or should) passing in a schema, as the docstring of to_parquet says.