# Specifying logical types (in particular, UUID) when writing parquet files from pyarrow

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

The pyarrow documentation builds a custom UUID type many times like this:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
class UuidType(pa.PyExtensionType):
    def __init__(self):
        pa.PyExtensionType.__init__(self, pa.binary(16))
    def __reduce__(self):
        return UuidType, ()
```

Coincidentally(?), there is a UUID logical type in parquet. I would like to be able to take a pyarrow table with UUIDs and write it to parquet, and have it specified as the UUID logical type.

This was asked and answered before [How to specify logical types when writing Parquet files from PyArrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172428/how-to-specify-logical-types-when-writing-parquet-files-from-pyarrow) in the context of fixed-length integers, and the solution was to update the version number and the problem solved itself. I would like to know how to specify the logical type manually, but I would also accept an answer that just makes it work for UUIDs.

Using the above class, I can try to build a table and write it.

```py
from uuid import uuid4
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

uuid_bytes = [u.bytes for u in [uuid4() for _ in range(100)]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'uuid_column': uuid_bytes})
schema = pa.schema([('uuid_column', UuidType())])
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)

with pq.ParquetWriter('uuid_data.parquet', schema) as writer:
  writer.write_table(table)
```

Printing the file schema with `ParquetFile` or inspecting it with `parquet-tools` shows that I have a file where a data set is `fixed_len_byte_array(16)`, but it does not have the `UUID` logical type.

Comment: any luck yet!? :)

Comment: @jtlz2 No, but the `UuidType` in the pyarrow documentation has changed due to a security issue.